# contador do while java textarea

Tags: java, string, contador

se supone que el joptionpane se repite la cantidad de veces que el usuario ingrese, pero por alguna razon solo lo hace una vez**

```
private void btnCorreosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
      int c=0;
      String prueba = ("");
      String pregunta = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("cauntos correos desea generar? "));
      String pregunta2 = pregunta.trim();
      String pregunta3 = pregunta2.replace(" ","");
      int contador = Integer.parseInt(pregunta3);
      String p;
      String result;
      String correo=("@chihuahua2.tecnm.mx");
      do
      {
      prueba = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prueba + "\n" + "ingrese su nombre: ");
      result = prueba.replace(" ","");
      c++;
      p = result+correo;
      txtCorreos.setText(p);
      }
      while(contador==c);
      
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mientras contador sea igual a c... si yo escribo 3 para contador, entra al do... suma 1 a c (c vale 1)... llega a la condicion.. .es contador igual a c? no.. entonces sale... vos queres que contador sea menor a c (puede ser menor o igual tambien, hay que chequear bien que queres)...

Comment: otra pregunta, el textArea solo muestra el correo que se realizo en en mismo ciclo en lugar de irse agrgando en fforma de lista

Comment: lo hace una vez por que estas usando el bucle `do while`,el cual ejecuta el código dentro y luego evalúa la condicional del bucle,el cual no se esta cumpliendo suponiendo que le das el valor de 2 al contador ,el valor de c=0 ;sera 1 dentro del do while,por ende `contador(2)==c(1)` nunca se cumplirá, la lógica correcta seria `while(c < contador);`

Comment: y.. es una lista, o un textbox??? son cosas muyyyyyyyyyy distintas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El contador sólo puede ser igual a la variable c una vez, en cuanto se modifique, ya no será igual, por tanto va a salir del bucle en cuanto se modifique, provocando que sólo se ejecute una vez. el bucle se debe ejecutar siempre que la cantidad de iteraciones sea MENOR que la cantidad máxima, en este caso la variable contador.

```
private void btnCorreosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
  int c=0;
  String prueba = "";
  String pregunta = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("cuantos correos desea generar? "));
  String pregunta2 = pregunta.trim();
  String pregunta3 = pregunta2.replace(" ","");
  int contador = Integer.parseInt(pregunta3);
  String p;
  String result;
  String correo=("@chihuahua2.tecnm.mx");
  do
  {
  prueba = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prueba + "\n" + "ingrese su nombre: ");
  result = prueba.replace(" ","");
  c++;
  p = result+correo;
  txtCorreos.setText(p);
  }
  while(c < contador);
  
}
```

> En lugar de usar un While para hacer un bucle de este tipo, le recomiendo mejor crear un bucle for:

```
for (int c = 0; c < contador; c++)
{
 prueba = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prueba + "\n" + "ingrese su nombre: ");
  result = prueba.replace(" ","");
  p = result+correo;
  txtCorreos.setText(p);
 }
```

Comment: entiendo, pero es un trabajo de la carrera y me pidieron usar de while